# Unable to change srcset by Javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I want to replace all dimensions 375x270 and 250x180 with 750x1280 in this code-snippet:

```
<img class="j-webview-product-image" imgsrc="
https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=375x270:format=jpg/path/sbcfc830c2d85c206/image/i547767095dfc0c2d/version/1475157973/image.jpg 375w,  
https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=250x180:format=jpg/path/sbcfc830c2d85c206/image/i547767095dfc0c2d/version/1475157973/image.jpg 250w"
sizes="(max-width: 480px) 100vw, 250px" src="
https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=250x180:format=jpg/path/sbcfc830c2d85c206/image/i547767095dfc0c2d/version/1475157973/image.jpg" 
alt="" title="" data-pin-nopin="true">
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andreaszeike/rtywrt9k/4/
- the code works well on all browsers except IE...

Comment: I really don't understand your code: `$("srcset").has('dimension=375x270')`?!  In fact, in all browsers your code is wrong. Just that `if($("srcset").has('dimension=375x270'))` is truthly on all browser because empty object is 'true' in js. Now you thing it works on other browsers because it give you some result... I doen't work on IE because... see Martin's answer below

Comment: Thats because I mixed up the snippet codes. sorry. replaced it in the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rtywrt9k/11/

Comment: But `$("srcset")` means select element(s) of type `srcset` and `has()` is a filtering function looking for element being anscestor of `'dimension=375x270'` (?) element. What you want is checking for **attribute** `srcset` and check for its value contains substring `dimension=375x270`. So: `if ($(this).attr('srcset').indexOf('dimension=375x270') != -1)` and this is the same for all your checks... So again, your code is completly **wrong on all browsers**, not just on IE

Comment: ...thank you for your help. I have an new fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/andreaszeike/6z838ghb/9/ . this one works on IE too.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2016, **srcset is not supported** by Internet Explorer: http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset

The replacing you are doing with jquery is working fine, it's just that Internet Explorer is ignoring the srcset altogether. You might try a srcset polyfill for IE, like this one: https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/